# How to get last commit code added in a particular file to another temp file

Tags: git, github, git-commit

This is the latest commit code change (added text "new line added").
How can I get this text to another temp file?

```
$ git show
commit c3fc4d58275740e5abc85219d75c2c00f3027a46 (HEAD -> my_branch, origin/my_branch)
Author: ********
Date:   ********

    test

diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
new file mode 100644
index 000000000..e833ecb7d
--- /dev/null
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+new line added
\ No newline at end of file
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use :
 `git diff | nano temp.txt`

**git diff** shows the changes between the working directory and the index. This shows what has been changed, but is not staged for a commit.

**|**  means the output from the left statement will be the input to the right statement.

**nano temp.txt** creates a file called temp.txt.

Comment: git show | nano temp.txt works but not what I want. This adds other commit information as well to the temp file. I only want the line of code added ("new line added") in my case.

Comment: Where do you want the file to be saved?

Comment: Local directory. Actually I only want the content of file. I will process the content and than delete the temp file. It's ok even if I don't create the temp file. Even if I get the content in the terminal it will be enough.

Comment: You can process what you want on the file "temp.txt". When you finish, write `rm temp.txt`

Comment: I am not able to get only the added code lines. I am getting other commit information with it.